# How to instantiate interface in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, interface

`setOnPlaceSelectedListener` takes an interface as argument. In Java, one could make an instance of that interface by overriding all of the methods on the get-go. How to do this in Kotlin?

```java
autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
        txtView.setText(place.getName()+","+place.getId());
        Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Status status) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can find the oficial documentation (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html)  you can create an object declaration:

```
window.addMouseListener(object : MouseAdapter() {
    override fun mouseClicked(e: MouseEvent) { ... }

    override fun mouseEntered(e: MouseEvent) { ... }
})
```